# How to fade out Django success messages using Javascript or CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to fade out Django success messages using a small Javascript script but cannot seem to get it to work. This is in my `base.html`:

```
{% if messages %}
{% for message in messages %}
<div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
    {{ message }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

```
<script>
var m = document.getElementsByClassName("alert");

setTimeout(function(){
   m.style.display = "none";
}, 3000);
</script>
```

Comment: Assuming your `div` is already correctly showing and the `<script>` tag is on the source, this is not a Django question, but rather a Javascript question.

Comment: I feel like this definitely falls under the `Django` tag because of the `{{ template tag }}` being referenced but I removed it to make you happy.

Comment: Django is only rendering your template, what you are looking for is a CSS animation/transition, or javascript handling of your DOM to update it . Does `m.style.display = "none";` works and hide the `<div>` ?

Comment: I didn't realize this could be handled with CSS. Is that the way people normally do it?

Comment: Django tags are essentially copy/paste which creates a file that gets sent to the client, so showing and fading messages will be done client side in JS.

Comment: @sebastienbarbier No. I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined at 9:108` in my console.

Comment: @(last message) That's the issue. JQuery (JS library, you will have to import) takes care of fade-outs pretty easily, so I recommend checking it out [here](https://api.jquery.com/fadeout/). Examples mid-way through the page.

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/cferdinandi/qgpxvhhb/23/) is a vanilla `css`/`JS` solution.

Comment: @DavidAlford Yes, CSS is usually the way to go for any sort of display styling or animation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django is only rendering your template, and return from a server side a HTML file which then need to be handled by your browser using CSS and javascript. An easy way to perform animation is using CSS transitions.

### CSS Transitions

```
<div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
    {{ message }}
</div>
```

```
.alert {
    positition: relative;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translateX(0px);
    transition: visibility 0s, opacity 250ms, transform 250ms;
}
.alert.hide {
    positition: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: translateX(-10px); // translateX, translateY, translateZ works well
    transition: visibility 0s 250ms, opacity 250ms, transform 250ms;
}
```

Then use Javascript to add a class to it:

```
<script>
var m = document.getElementsByClassName("alert");  // Return an array

setTimeout(function(){
   if (m && m.length) {
       m[0].classList.add('hide');
   }
}, 3000);
</script>
```

## CSS animation library

This is the verbose version which consist of **writting your own animation** and configure exactly as you need, but a simple solution could be to use a **CSS animation library** like [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) which provide a set of amazing transitions on the same principle.

Just be careful not using too much of them, you do not want your application to look like a christmas tree .

Comment: I am not going to lie; this seems like a lot of work for one simple task.

Comment: It is not really, takes very little time to write when you know about it and it's very low level so perfect to customize. You can use libraries like [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) which is basically a set of ready to use animation.