# CSS onclick animation

Tags: html, css, django

I have the following messages block at my Django application, see below. It's working beautifully if new messages appear but what I don't understand is how can I also play a "fadeOut" animation as soon as the onclick function gets hit.

It would be awesome if I could also execute an animation if I click on the cross, can smb help? If possible not using JavaScript

```css
.messages {
  position: fixed;
  width: 235px;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #bfbfbf4a;
  padding: 2.5px;
}

.closebtn {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  top: -10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: -15px;
}

.dot {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #b0b0b0a3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="animated slideInRight messages">
  <span class="closebtn dot" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';"><span class="cross">×</span></span>
  <span><li class="tag">Message 1</li></span>
  <span><li class="tag">Message 2</li></span>
  <span><li class="tag">Message 3</li></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not a Django issue but an HTML/JavaScript/CSS. Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and post a [mcve] of your efforts with ONLY HTML, JS and relevant CSS

Comment: Well of course this is not a Django issue, basically there is not issue at all, I just needed to know toI could possibly play a animation as soon as I click onto the cross

Comment: So can you do what I ask? Click `[<>]` and create a [mcve] using ONLY HTML and CSS?

Comment: Your HTML is not valid. You need UL to contain LIs that can contain spans, not spans with LIs - I made you an HTML and CSS only snippet

Comment: Look at CSS transitions

Answer (score 0):

Funnily enough, I just did exactly this today. This was my solution.

here's my message snippet for the template:

```
{% for message in messages %}
<div class="container-fluid py-1 mx-auto" id="message_container">
    <div class="alert {{ message.tags }} alert-dismissable" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="alert">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        {{ message }}
    </div>
</div>
{% empty %}
{% endfor %}
```

And here's the code I use to fade out, and then remove the element.

```
function fadeOut(elementToFade) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elementToFade);

    element.style.opacity -= 0.1;
    if (element.style.opacity <= 0.0) {
        element.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        setTimeout("fadeOut(\"" + elementToFade + "\")", 150);
    }
};

var message_ele = document.getElementById("message_container");
var pauseBeforeFadeout = 5000;

setTimeout(function () {
    message_ele.style.opacity = 1.0;
    if (message_ele !== null) {
        fadeOut("message_container");
    }
}, pauseBeforeFadeout);
```

Couple of notes:
I default the opacity to 1.0 before decrementing, since it doesn't seem to be set by default which means it doesn't work.

Once opacity hits zero, I actually remove the element. You may want to just leave it hidden though, in which case just ensure opacity is exactly 0 instead of setting `display` to `none`

Comment: Okay well the point for me is that my application is free of any JS, I simply dont like it and for most of the time the animated framework from https://animate.style/ works just fine for me. My Idear was to first let the message fade in using the css effect and then use the onclick to let it fadeout again

Comment: OK, fair enough :) I'm no CSS expert, so keeping an eye on the answers in case there's a better way of doing this!

Comment: Thanks dude :D. Nice conversation anyways

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can add a property to your classes, so it will make it nicely disappear

```js
function addClass() {
  var element = document.getElementById("div");
  element.classList.add("hidden");
}
```

```css
.visible {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 2s linear;
}


.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s 2s, opacity 2s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="div" class="visible" onclick="addClass()" >click me</div>
```

Comment: No JS please, can't use it for this specific project/client

Comment: I put some JS as demonstration, what you need is the ```transition``` and ```opacity``` css properties that will handle the animation :)

Comment: Well the classes that should handle the animation already present, see classes animated slideInRight. These are from https://animate.style/

Comment: I see what you mean. So I think the Django simply removes the element from the DOM, making it disappear. There's no way to animate that. It's similar to what happens with ```display: none``` which just remove the block, you cannot animate it.

Comment: Here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58617996/how-to-fade-out-django-success-messages-using-javascript-or-css) you can see a similar case, and they used JS to add the class, similar to my solution suggest. Sorry, cannot help more than that :(

Comment: No problem, anyways thanks for your intentions, I hopped there might be a way to accomplish this.